# Maven archetype for basic spring hibernate struts2 application

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven-2, struts2, maven-archetype

I am looking for a basic maven archetype which can help me create a spring hibernate struts2

application. I have tried using appfuse but it sucks. It took more than half an hour to

download n number of dependencies and the project it created was having errors also.

if you know anyother maven archetype please tell me.

Thanks

Shekhar

Answer (score 3):

```
mvn archetype:create \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.appfuse.archetypes \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-basic-struts \
    -DremoteRepositories=http://static.appfuse.org/releases \
    -DarchetypeVersion=2.0.1 \
    -DgroupId=fr.xebia.blog.voiture \
    -DartifactId=voiture-app
```

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't an archetype that suits you, just use the default archetype, and add in the dependencies you need yourself.

If you are having download issues, then use a different mirror for your remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

If appfuse is not working, consider posting errors reported.
Also, create your own maven archetype for spring/hibernate/struts2 application as mentioned in [this](http://bodez.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/creating-a-maven-archetype-struts2spring-based-web-application/) blog post.